# Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I was using JPA `AttributeConverter` with spring boot 1.2.1 RELEASE and it worked fine. But I get the following error after upgrading to spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3248)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rafito.spring.boot.domain.TimestampPersistenceConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(TimestampPersistenceConverter.java:16)
    at rafito.spring.boot.domain.TimestampPersistenceConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(TimestampPersistenceConverter.java:10)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:97)
```

I am not setting serviceBeginTime and serviceEndTime in my POST JSON currently. But this wasn't giving me a null pointer before I upgraded spring boot version.

**Converter class**

```
@Converter
public class TimestampPersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, Timestamp> {


    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Long aLong) {
        return new Timestamp(aLong);
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return timestamp.getTime();
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Column(name = "service_begin_time")
@Convert(converter = TimestampPersistenceConverter.class)
Long serviceBeginTime;

@Column(name = "service_end_time")
@Convert(converter = TimestampPersistenceConverter.class)
Long serviceEndTime;
```

**Database fields**

```
service_begin_time timestamp without time zone,
service_end_time timestamp without time zone,
```

Comment: and why don't you look at the stack trace of the exception, maybe there is a nested exception. Better still post it in the question so then people have information

Comment: so there's an NPE in your converter ... so perhaps fix your converter to cater for nulls.

Comment: Yes..That was my workaround `@Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Long aLong) {
        if (aLong == null)
            return null;
        return new Timestamp(aLong);
    }`

Comment: This could also happen if the set of named values passed to your  `AttributeConverter`  doesn't have a match with the original data received by the converter. I mean this is an obvious potential reason, but stating it for anyone like me who won't suspect data!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Added a null check as that was the easiest.

```
@Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Long aLong) {
        if (aLong == null)
            return null;
        return new Timestamp(aLong);
    }
```